Chrome extension, create_root seems not work
I want to float new window(Note compoent) when i clicked 'open Note' button on default popup page.
but nothing happen.
What am I doing wrong? When I manipulate the DOM directly with inline styles, it works.
However, when I try to run note.js to display the React DOM, it doesn't work. despite of that build file for note.js is being generated.
manifest
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "react-boilerplate",
  "description": "react-boilerplate for chrome extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "React Boilerplate",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "bookmarks",
    "storage",
    "identity"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
}

Webpack
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    popup: path.resolve("src/popup/index.tsx"),
    options: path.resolve("src/options/index.tsx"),
    background: path.resolve("src/background/background.ts"),
    contentScript: path.resolve("src/contentScript/contentScript.ts"),
    newTab: path.resolve("src/tabs/index.tsx"),
    note: path.resolve("src/note/index.tsx"),
  },

// popup.tsx ( default popup )
import React from "react";
import "./popup.css";
import Button from "../tabs/components/base/Button";

const Popup = () => {
  const createFloatingNote = async function () {
    console.log("hello world");
    const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
    if (tabs.length > 0) {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      const url = new URL(activeTab.url);
      chrome.scripting
        .executeScript({
          target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
          files: ["note.js"],
        })
        .then(() => console.log("script injected"));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl text-green-500">Pop up Page</h1>
      <Button onClick={createFloatingNote}>Open Note</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Popup;

// note/index.tsx
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import Note from "./note";

function init() {
  const appContainer = document.createElement("div");
  const body = document.body;
  body.appendChild(appContainer);
  if (!appContainer) {
    throw new Error("Can not find AppContainer");
  }
  const root = createRoot(appContainer);
  root.render(<Note />);
}

init();

note/note.tsx
import React from "react";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const Container = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 10000000000;
`;

function Note() {
  return <Container>hello</Container>;
}

export default Note;

I tried sending messages to background.js and run same script but not working...:(

Make sure note.js is present in the folder of the html file, otherwise specify the full path from the root of the build folder e.g. '/js/note.js'. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Sorry to confusing you, i mean that i want to  manipulate browser's DOM
but root.render() don't seem to work
i posted issue.  could you take a look please ?
https://github.com/sae1013/react-chrome-extension/issues/1

Sounds like this code creates a custom element? In that case you'll have to do it in the MAIN world.
